# SQLite db not returning any rows

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

For my app i am trying to save highscores to a database stored on my android device named "highscores.db". Now I am having a problem that the mysql is not returning any rows at al, so i would guess that either my inserting is going wrong or my retrieving is going on. I have no idea at all what is wrong (first time sqlite user).

DBHandler.java

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "highscores.db";
public static final String TABLE_HIGHSCORES = "highscores";
public static final String COLUMN_WAVE = "wave";
public static final String COLUMN_MONEY = "money";
public static final String COUKN_ZOMBIEKILL = "zombiekill";

public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HIGHSCORES + "(" + COLUMN_WAVE + " INTEGER, " +
            COLUMN_MONEY + " DOUBLE, " +
            COUKN_ZOMBIEKILL + " INTEGER " + ")";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

//Upgrade db
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_HIGHSCORES);
    onCreate(db);
}

//add new row
public boolean addHighScore(Highscore highscore) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_WAVE, highscore.getWave());
    values.put(COLUMN_MONEY, highscore.getMoneyLeftOver());
    values.put(COUKN_ZOMBIEKILL, highscore.getZombiekill());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_HIGHSCORES, null, values);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

//Get database info
public ArrayList<Highscore> getHighScores(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM highscores";

    int wave = 0;
    double money = 0;
    int zombiekill = 0;
    Highscore hs = null;
    ArrayList<Highscore> highscores = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(c.moveToNext()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("wave")) != null){
            wave = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("wave")));
        }
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("money")) != null){
            money = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("money")));
        }
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("zombiekill")) != null){
            zombiekill = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("zombiekill")));
        }
        hs = new Highscore(wave,money,zombiekill);
        highscores.add(hs);
    }

    db.close();
    return highscores;
}
```

}

Also, i do not know where to view this database to check wether or not it is being filled. Many give an explanation where it can be found but I do not know how to get there.

~Thanks in advance

EDIT1.0 changed public ArrayList getHighScores()

```
    public ArrayList<Highscore> getHighScores(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM highscores";

    int wave = 0;
    double money = 0;
    int zombiekill = 0;
    Highscore hs = null;
    ArrayList<Highscore> highscores = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("wave")) != null){
            wave = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("wave")));
        }
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("money")) != null){
            money = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("money")));
        }
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("zombiekill")) != null){
            zombiekill = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("zombiekill")));
        }
        hs = new Highscore(wave,money,zombiekill);
        highscores.add(hs);
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    db.close();
    return highscores;
}
```

Still not working

EDIT2.0: This is how im handling saving

```
 DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        handler.addHighScore(new Highscore(10,30,55));
    }
```

this is how im handling retrieving on different file:

```
    DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);
    HighScoreSingleton.getInstance().setHighscores(handler.getHighScores());
```

Comment: How many rows u added.. If u added only one row.. As per ur movetofisrt call n den movenext call , u won't get any data.

Comment: Your code is working right, I copied your methods and I can retrieve the values. Your problem is how you are using those methods. Check if you are handling the high score data correctly outside this class.

Comment: However, now i need to figure out how to retrieve data from the db once i restart the app because it onl retrieves data when i inserted it and then retrieve it but not a stand alone trieve on the older db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Benjamín Molina i found that i was handling the output wrong.

I only had to update the handling of the code.
Update, put importing and selecting on the same java class or create a singleton that will keep track of tehs ame instance of the call to the dbhandler.

```
DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        handler.addHighScore(new Highscore(10,30,55));
    }

    HighScoreSingleton.getInstance().setHighscores(handler.getHighScores());
```

However i still found that if i close the app and restart it without first adding new data into the db, all data is lost, how do i retrieve that data from a previous made db.